# Comparing CGPoint and NSNumber

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

This is my first post, so be kind :)

I've looked around for solutions but can't seem to find one. Problem may be asking the question in a way that google will return useful results.

So, I have an NSMutableArray (called boardColCoords), and I have CGPoint (called touchLocation). I want to compare the two so that I can snap a UIImageView location to the proper coordinate in the boardColCoords array.

Here's the relevant code:

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

NSNumber *boardSquareX = [boardColCoords objectAtIndex:i];

if (touchLocation.x - boardSquareX <= 12)
{
}
```

I know that 12 will eventually have to be changed, but I just want to get the subtraction working first. The specific error I get is:

Invalid operands to binary expression ('CGFloat' (aka 'float') and "NSNumber *).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NSNumber is a wrapper, you have to "extract" it's value with something like `floatValue` to compare like that:

```
if (touchLocation.x - [boardSquareX floatValue] <= 12)
```

Comment: Thanks, as soon as I have enough rep to upvote, I'll upvote this.

Answer (score 2):

To get a float value from NSNumber, you would do

```
[boardSquareX floatValue];
```

Comment: All good answers. Awarding the +1 to the one with the least reputation score

Comment: @Ben if they're all helpful, why not upvote them all? They all took the time to answer the question, and answer it correctly...

Comment: I'll upvote all of them as soon as I have enough rep. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the primitive number from `boardSquareX`.

```
if (touchLocation.x - [boardSquareX floatValue] <= 12)
{
}
```